# How do I correctly disable a mac-style application menu in classic desktop edition?

Tags: 10.10, menu, appmenu, ayatana

I installed "indicator-applet-appmenu" and tried the same for "global menu". It does not work for the most of applications and does not seem convenient with my monitors configuration.

The problem is, that now (despite I have no "appmenu applet" active), some applications, for example **UEx** (UltraEdit for Linux) don't show their menus in their windows, so I need to activate global menu applet to use them.

How can I fix this? I am afraid (because I am on a 3G connection with limited traffic) that if I just remove indicator-applet-appmenu package, the problem won't solve and I will loose the last way to access menus in those programs.

Comment: I think the answer is in your question. If removing the package loses menus from both menu bar and global menu, you can always have it back by re-installing it (Press `Alt+F2` and type `sudo aptitude install indicator-applet-appmenu` against command, select "Run in Terminal" and click "OK").

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug. Ultraedit probably needs to be tested, you can help contribute by checking out how to debug the menu here:

http://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationMenu

For the menu itself, just remove the applet from the panel, no need to remove the package.